# For what c is $F(x)=c\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-|x|} dx$ a distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory

I know the properties of distribution functions, that as $x$ approaches negative infinite $F(x)= 0$ and as $x$ approaches positive infinite then $F(x) = 1$. We can't use the first option to find $c$, so looking at the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches infinite, I'm not sure what to do with the limit. The integral can be looked at as just $e^{-x}$ evaluated from negative infinity to $x$, which is $e^{-x}$? and then we take the limit of that as $x$ approaches infinite?

Comment: You probably want $e^{-|t|}dt$ inside your integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\, dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 e^x \, dx$, so that your integral is 
$$
c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|}\, dx = 2c\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\, dx.
$$
The last integral is easy to compute. You just have to use that $F(x)=1$ as $x$ approaches positive infinite.

Comment: Ok the next part is what I am most confused on. So, if we set that equal to 1, we can't solve for c because the integral from 0 to infinity of e ^(-x) is zero?

Comment: Ok I solved that incorrectly, the integral of e^(-x) is 1, so then we would need c = 1/2

Comment: Exactly, well done.